# Understanding to use "Of" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

*This serves both **as a way** of making amends to society and **of** avoiding the potentially harmful consequences of a period in prison.*

Is this the bold "Of" word same with "as a way of avoiding..." comes from the start of this sentence?

Comment: Yes: "of making amends to society" and "of avoiding the potentially harmful" form a coordination of preposition phrases functioning as complement of "way".

Comment: The word **both** is poorly positioned.

Comment: Thank you for answers.

Comment: way of making amends and way of avoiding x. How could it not be? of in English is only ever one thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have understood it correctly. It's like saying, "...both *as a way of* making amends to society and *as a way of* avoiding..." The word "**both**" tells the listener/reader to expect **two** results/outcomes.

Although it's acceptable in colloquial English, "serves both as a way of" sounds a little awkward. The usual formula might be "This *serves as both* X and Y", where X and Y are nouns or noun phrases. Your sentence can't be made to fit that formula.

In *formal* English your sentence might be better re-written as:

> This serves as a way of making amends to society **while** avoiding the
> potentially harmful consequences of a period in prison.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.